# User names in postgres docker image logs

Tags: postgresql, logs, docker

I'm looking to get thorough logs of user activity attributable back to users from the official docker image of Postgres.  I'm running my docker image like so:

```
docker run --name pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 54320:5432 postgres -c log_statement=all -c log_line_prefix=`t=%m u=%u db=%d pid=[%p]:
```

But I'm getting logs that look like:

```
PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.1 (Debian 13.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-01-24 11:58:13 UTC
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
FATAL:  database "test" does not exist
LOG:  statement: SELECT VERSION()
LOG:  statement: SHOW ALL
LOG:  statement: SELECT datName FROM pg_database WHERE datAllowConn ORDER BY datName
LOG:  statement: CREATE DATABASE "test"
LOG:  statement: /* setup database */

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
       id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
       name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
       email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
       password_hash varchar(255) NOT NULL
    );

    /* fill with seed data */
    INSERT INTO users
    (name, email, password_hash) VALUES
    ('Robert', 'robert@example.com', 'hash'),
    ('Bob', 'bob@example.com', 'new_hash'),
    ('Rob', 'rob@example.com', 'another hash');
    /* read data, write data using good user */

    /* read data, write data */
LOG:  statement: SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE source = 'session';
```

Which doesn't give me a good timestamp or attribute the activity to a user.  What am I doing wrong?